# Is there a name for the range from negative one to one?

Tags: terminology, signal-processing

I do a lot of DSP (digital signal processing), and in compressing a signal and any number of other operations, I frequently need to constrain it to the range $[-1, 1]$. Now, I know that this isn't quite normalization, because normalization (at least in my typical use) implies $[0, 1]$.

In spite of this, I see the $[-1, 1]$ range so often I can't help but suspect that there is a formal name for it. What is it called?

Comment: If I had to name it, I'd probably call it the 1D unit ball.

Comment: It's often called the closed unit ball around the origin, or simply the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept that as an answer if you care to post it below.

Comment: But yet, but yet… Most people would understand “closed unit ball around the origin”, I suppose, but for those who may not, you’d better say exactly what you’re talking about the first time you use that terminology.

Comment: I'm a professional writer and I've already considered that, but thank you.

Comment: have you found any better term than the one suggested?  I am having the same naming issue, in the same field.

Comment: @MikeNakis No, I went with the accepted one (closed unit ball). It's terse, easy to pronounce, and as long as it's clearly (and visibly) defined early in the paper it shouldn't be problematic for readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normed space $X = (X,\|\cdot\|)$, the set
$$B(0,1) = \{ x \in x : \|x\| < 1 \} $$
is called the [*open*] *unit ball*.  In $\mathbb{R}^2$ this set is a disk (like a coin or pancake), and in $\mathbb{R}^3$ this set is a solid three-dimensional ball.  The same definition still applies in $\mathbb{R}$, where
$$ (-1,1) = B(0,1) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : |x|<1 \}.$$
Thus it is quite reasonable to call this set the *one-dimensional unit ball*.  Note that, without modification, it is typically assumed that the unit ball is open.  The question is about the closed interval $[-1,1]$, which is then the *closed unit ball* in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the set
$$ [-1,1] = \overline{B(0,1)} = \{ x\in\mathbb{R} : |x| \le 1 \} $$
(note the weakening of the inequality).